# Having multiple tex and bib files for a PhD thesis

Tags: bibliographies, multibib, multiple-files

I want to use multiple and separate `.tex` and `.bib` files for my PhD thesis.

Since some of the `.bib` files are having same entries (possibly with different reference names), I prefer to force the `.tex` files uses its own corresponding `.bibligraphy` to avoid conflict across different bibs. Is there a way to do that INSTEAD of using a single line putting all bibs together : `\bibliography{thesis,part1,part2,part3}` and I would prefer to keep using `bibtex`.

MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,openright,english,italian]{book}% twoside!
\usepackage[twoside=true]{geometry}
\usepackaages[...]

\begin{document}
\input{chapters/acknowledge}
\input{chapters/thesis}
\input{chapters/part1}  // in this file there is \bibliography{part1}
\input{chapters/part2}  // in this file there is \bibliography{part2}
\input{chapters/part3}  // in this file there is \bibliography{part3}

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}
\small
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{thesis}  // only for other sections

\end{document}
```

Comment: With biblatex/biber you could use `refsection`.

Comment: Except switching to `biblatex` ?

Comment: It is much easier to do this with Biblatex/Biber. There are options for BibTeX but I don't know if they handle separate `.bib`s in the way you want.

Comment: You can check the packages for multi bibs: https://www.ctan.org/topic/bibtex-multi. But I don't know if one of them can handle separate bibs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Kbib](http://users.tpg.com.au/thachly/kbib/) (if you have kde or macports kde) and merge two bibfiles. It will detect conflicts and ask you which one to keep.